# ReloadData does not refresh the Tableview

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm using the UIViewController  where it has the table view control in it.

In the ViewDidLoad event I initialize the tableview, here is the code

```
listView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
listView.delegate = self;
listView.dataSource = self;
listView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

then I call the webservice to populate the NSMutableArray. In the `connectionDidFinishLoading` event I copy the `NSmutableArray` to the datasource.

```
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
{
    listData = [parser.localTaskList copy];
    [listView reloadData];          
}
else 
{
    NSLog (@"Error parsing Facilities");        
}
```

Here the code in the tableview events.

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listData count];    
}
```

Cell for row at IndexPath event.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *EditCellIdentifier = @" editcell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EditCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:EditCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //}
        if ([listData count] > 0) {

            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:kLabelRect];
            label.tag = kCellLabelTag;
            label.text=[[listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TaskID];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
            [label release];

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:unselectedImage];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 10.0, 23.0, 23.0);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            imageView.hidden = !inPseudoEditMode;
            imageView.tag = kCellImageViewTag;
            [imageView release];
        }   
    }



    [UIView beginAnimations:@"cell shift" context:nil];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kCellLabelTag];
    //label.text = [listData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    label.frame = (inPseudoEditMode) ? kLabelIndentedRect : kLabelRect;

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kCellImageViewTag];
    NSNumber *selected = [selectedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    imageView.image = ([selected boolValue]) ? selectedImage : unselectedImage;
    imageView.hidden = !inPseudoEditMode;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // set the default detail button
    if (inPseudoEditMode) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Number of Sections event

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;   
}
```

But the reloadData does not refresh the UITableview.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find better success if you move the line:

`label.text=[[listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TaskID];`

from inside the cell creation block to a point after that block. I notice that you've got a similar line after the block, but it's commented out. All the per-row setup of the cell should happen after the cell creation block.

Comment: I tried moving the code below the cell creation block, but the reloaddata does not hit cellForRowAtIndexPath method at all. It hits the numberOfRowsInSection but not the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function. I think you will notice that function IS called after you call reloadData, but because you have static cell identifier - none of the cells get re-created.

There are number of ways to dealing with this. Let me know if I'm right.

Comment: I tried with breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath function. It does not even hit that function after the reloaddata method call.